# How BIP 39 tool recovers all my private and public keys which was generated in ledger nano s

Tags: blockchain, ether, wallets, bitcoin, ledger-nano-s

I followed the faq in [ledger nano s](https://ledger.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/restoring-your-ethers-eth-or-etc-without-a-ledger-nano-s).

This says that I can retrieve the private and public key. Does it mean that using the 24 word seed we can generate the same set of private and public keys in same order as it was created in my ledger nano s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the process is fully deterministic and nothing involved in it is random except for the original seed, so you should be able to regenerate the same addresses in the same order.